# Qt, PyQt and SIP compatibility issue. (TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable)

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt4.8, python-sip

I've been trying to compile Qt and PyQt for a couple days and couldn't get it work with the software that was working in the previous Qt/PyQt version. The error can be recreate when I do this,

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
unicode(QtCore.QString())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable
```

It's working if I add 'utf-8' to unicode command second option

```
unicode(QtCore.QString(), "utf-8")
```

The software I'm trying to run do this conversion a LOT and I don't want to change them.
Really stuck here any suggestion would help.

```
CentOS 6.4
Qt 4.8.6
PyQt 4.11.2
SIP 4.16.3
Python 2.6.6
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever thought about upgrading to Python 2.7.8? https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.8/ I'm not sure about it but that might fix the problem.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem using the same versions (although the problem is not present with python-2.7). AKAIK, PyQt4 still supports python-2.6.x, so you should report this as a bug on the [pyqt mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Comment: My company is still using 2.6.6 but if this can solve the problem it's a good reason to update :) I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed. It's working with Python 2.7